# Matlab: Change variable resolution and names for viewing regression trees

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, decision-tree

Using `treeMine = fitctree(....)` I can generate a decision tree but the tree is very big, and therefore very difficult to convey information, when using `view(treeMine,'Mode','Graph')`

[image]

Therefore my question is if it is possible to change variable names x1-x9 to other names to make it human understandable and if I could force the numbers to be represented by engineering notation meaning 10e3.

Does anybody know how this can be done?

**Minimal Example**

Minimal example can be to use [Matlabs own car example](https://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/classification-trees-and-regression-trees.html#buq4zob-1):

```
load carsmall
idxNaN = isnan(MPG + Weight);
X = Weight(~idxNaN);
Y = MPG(~idxNaN);
n = numel(X);

rng(1) % For reproducibility
idxTrn = false(n,1);
idxTrn(randsample(n,round(0.5*n))) = true; % Training set logical indices
idxVal = idxTrn == false;                  % Validation set logical indices

Mdl = fitrtree(X(idxTrn),Y(idxTrn));
view(Mdl,'Mode','graph')
```

How do you then specify the value resolution and variable name

Comment: What new variable names do you want? That's a read-only property btw

Comment: @SardarUsama I wanted to give them variable names of what they represent, but that is not possible based on your read only. Where did you see this?

I imagined one could access the properties with `set(gca,...)` or similar, but did not manage to do this

Comment: @SardarUsama x1 could instead be women, x2 age, and so forth

Comment: It's not an axis. So `gca` has nothing to do here. Its the `PredictorNames` that you're trying to change and if you try to do that, MATLAB will tell you that it is read-only

Comment: @SardarUsama bummer, is there another way to illustrate the tree then? Because it would be nice to have the tree specific to ones data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the names: It's a bit a poor example because you use only one predictor (weight), but you can change the name with the 'PredictorNames' name-value pair, e.g.

```
Mdl = fitrtree(X(idxTrn),Y(idxTrn),'PredictorNames',{'weight'});
```

If you were to use more predictors you just have to add more elements to the cell array, e.g.

```
'PredictorNames',{'weight','age','women'}
```

I don't know about the numbers tough.

Comment: Is it also possible to change the number resolution?

Comment: I wouldn't know how - but plotting isn't really my specialty. All I can say is that there isn't a direct option for it.